# how i can pass string variable with url in load function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i have variable  fileVal takes path of file like uploads/import/abc.pdf

var fileVal = $('#fileimport').val();

here fileVal takes path of file like uploads/import/abc.pdf

i have to send this file path  as url variable to a php file
and then display result on messagediv.
like

```
  $('#messagediv').load('../xyz.php?file='+fileVal);
```

here without url variable, its working perfect getting values to the messagediv.

But where as using url variable its not.

How i can solve this?

Comment: Well, don't send it as URL. Break it in several get variables. Like `...xyz.php?path=uploads-import&filename=abc.pdf` then construct the url in xyz.php by replacing the dashes of the path with forward slashes and adding the filename at the end

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how it's constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var fileVal =  encodeURIComponent($('#fileimport').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine except you have a syntax error

```
// $var fileVal = $('#fileimport').val();
var fileVal = $('#fileimport').val();
```